# Как можно проверить не подменилили мне .so файл?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

В папке  jniLibs содержатся .so файлы. Как я могу быть уверен что файлы которые там  это мои, что их не подменили?

Comment: А вы сами пробовали их подменить? Если не ошибаюсь, Андроид не позволяет загрузить любую библиотеку - только те что были упакованы в APK. И смею предположить, что при загрузке он сверяет их контрольную сумму с записанной в `MANIFEST.MF`. Если всё не так - то вы сами можете рассчитать эти суммы и сверить со своими, где-то спрятанными. Но это только дополнительный шажок для злодея))

Comment: Думаю, если пользователь захочет, он просто соберёт себе нужный apk с нужными ему файлами, отключит проверку подписи и установит всё что ему нужно. Все проверки, которые вы добавите, также отключит, если понадобится.

Comment: Контрольные суммы - не?

Comment: посчитать хэшы имеете ввиду и сравнивать ?я тоже об этом подумал